# Is there a better way to define a "wrapped" JSON object without violating TS principles?

Tags: typescript

I recently began working with TypeScript and have come across an issue which I am curious if TypeScript provides any facilities for.  I am reaching out to a web service which accepts data requests in the following format:

```
{
    "data": {
        "country": "US"
        "customerType": "Internal"
        "customer": "ABC"
    }
}
```

As you can see, the actual JSON request is "wrapped" with the "data" object, thereby requiring me to define my classes as such:

```
export class CalculatorRequest {
    data: CalculatorRequestData
}

export class CalculatorRequestData {
    country: string;
    customerType: string;
    customer: string;
}
```

Is there any way to avoid having to have the secondary, internal data class of type "CalculatorRequestData"?

I understand I can craft my request to avoid needing the internal class, but I would like to see if there are any more efficient options.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any reason why you are doing it. The data property is probably just a the way your backend structures its responses. You probably should have a backend service in your frontend which makes the requests for your other services and just hands back the raw response data. The requesting service should then use this data the way it wants e.g. build an object out of it like you would with your `CalculatorRequestData` class.

Comment: Good point!  I understand where you're coming from, just wanted to see what sort of options TypeScript provides in this situation, for instance Amy's answer below.  Thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a generic will let you only make the 'data' objects, while you'll only ever need the one 'request' object.

```
export class ApiRequest<T> {
    data: T
}

export class CalculatorRequestData {
    country: string;
    customerType: string;
    customer: string;
}

// no extra request object needed, regardless of how many requests you have
export class FoooData {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
}
```

Comment: Exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.  Thanks Amy!